# Can't open terminal in vscode on os x 10.11.6

Tags: macos, terminal, visual-studio-code

Have installed VS Code (ver 1.27.2) on os x 10.11.6. All settings are still default values. When attempt to open the integrated terminal, a pane opens with usual headers, but no terminal prompt. Is this a known issue? Is there a fix?

Comment: Are you pressing _Control + Shift + `_ ?

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the terminal window, on the left side, there are selectable options with the following name: Problems, Output, Debug Console, and Terminal.  The terminal on my machine usually opens in the Output mode. This option is a window with nothing in it yet. If I click on the Terminal mode I get the regular looking terminal with prompt.

Comment: I get the Terminal pane and there is one tab at the left "TERMINAL," and the dropdown that says Bash at the right and the line of control buttons. But no actual terminal that allows me to enter and run code.

Comment: And in an opened folder, the list of folder items are each followed by an upper case "U". Unlike the folder contents appearance when SV Code runs in Ubuntu. I suspect there are some parameters that must be set to different values from the default, but I don't know what they are. and the Ubuntu operation simply runs correctly (so far as I can tell) out-of-the-box. So, I'm stumped on running SV Code under OS X 10.11.6.

Comment: The language I'm using is Lua-5.3.5

Comment: And I get same results when I attempt to open Terminal using the keystrokes CTRL-` and also CTRL-SHFT-`.